# YAML ofstream emitter

Tags: yaml-cpp

I find this example:

```
ofstream ofstr("output.yaml");
YAML::Emitter out(ofstr);
out << some_large_document;

// not necessary anymore:
// ofstr << out.c_str()
```

But when i try use it, i have:

```
D:\work\C\map.cpp||In function `int main()':|
D:\work\C\map.cpp|24|error: no matching function for call to `YAML::Emitter::Emitter(std::ofstream&)'|
D:\work\C\yaml-cpp\emitter.h|23|note: candidates are: YAML::Emitter::Emitter(YAML::Emitter&)|
D:\work\C\yaml-cpp\emitter.h|25|note:                 YAML::Emitter::Emitter()|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no constructor to `YAML::Emitter` that takes a stream. (Where did you find that example?)

Instead, you *do* need to use the commented out line:

```
ofstream ofstr("output.yaml");
YAML::Emitter out;
out << some_large_document;
ofstr << out.c_str(); // is necessary!
```

Comment: @spumer, where on that page does it construct a `YAML::Emitter` by passing a stream?